# What are the benefits of content based addressing in Git?

Tags: git, sha

The question:

Git uses content based file addressing system (that is it uses blobs and trees hashes as a "file names"). I was wondering what are the benefits of such addressing system?

I can clearly see **some** of the benefits, but those are minor:

1. If someone changes some file in the git repo, it will break all the commits which point to it. Thus you will for sure know that something bad has happend. But is it really that useful?
2. Using hash for a file decouples *real file name* from its content and thus you can "cheaply" rename a file...

I feel that the true reason for using sha for file addressing is quite different. Can anyone explain?

P.S. The clarification. The question is about WHY Git uses hashes for addressing files and not HOW does it do so. I know somewhat of a HOW, I need to know WHY.

P.P.S. There is an article about Git principals and [why Git looks so strange](https://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) (because it should be used on a machine where no other software except for core OS and a text editor present), but still this article mentions only this WHY:

> *if you calculate sha of a file and this sha is already in the objects folder, then you know that you need not store it again, since sha
> depends on contents.*

All right, this WHY I get. Any other WHY use *content addressable file system*?

Comment: The benefits you've listed already seem plenty sufficient to me. Do fast, absolute-as-absolute-gets content integrity checks and redundancy elimination in a content tracker really not seem like sufficiently desirable qualities?

Comment: Well, I thought maybe there are other more principal benefits.

Comment: "If someone changes some file in the git repo, it will break all the commits which point to it." Commits don't point to files.

Comment: yeah, I know, but the commit will be "broken" since it points to trees which points to blobs etc.

Comment: Worth pointing out: other version control systems use other methods. They work. This proves that the *way* Git does version control is not the only way one can do version control. Ultimately, then, the answer to "why" is just: *because Linus Torvalds wrote it that way*. There are other ways that work. If you like them, consider using one of those other VCSes (Mercurial, p4, bazaar, darcs, etc).

Answer (score 6):

One of the most common things git needs to do is to compare two versions of a project.  Because the object storage (commits, trees, and blobs) are content addressable, this can be done very quickly by comparing the "filenames".

Additionally when storing content, it is very easy to see if it's a copy of something you're already storing, so you can avoid storing a duplicate.

Comment: So once you commit something, Git recalculates all the hashes for all the files in the working directory and looks for a match in its "DB"? Right? Looks like a waste to me but, yeah, how can you track which files changed and how have they changed.... Ok. Got it. So in short: Git uses hash for files as a method to track changes. Is it THE MAIN reason for using hashes? Are there any other good reasons?

Comment: No, git does not recalculate al the hashes for all the files in the working directory.  It relies on fstat to know if a working file has potentially changed (which is reliable unless someone is deliberately trying to hide a change) - and it can be configured to skip over that check as well for subdirectories where even that would be a waste of time.  Also, that is relevant when you `add` - not when you `commit`, which doesn't really involve the working directory.  The process of `add`ing calculates the hash of any potentially-changed object and stores it in the index as needed

Comment: As @MarkAdelsberger said, Git doesn't have to re-hash every file every time. Besides the fact that `git commit` simply reads what's in Git's index (this includes the list of file-names-and-blob-hash-IDs), `git add` gets to skip over a lot of stuff via the cache aspect of Git's index, which stores OS-level `lstat` data. (It's `lstat` not `fstat` because Git does not have the files open all the time.) The cache can also communicate with file system monitoring, if your OS offers this.

Answer (score 6):

This hash is a unique ID of an object. You could do the same with blobs that you store in DB - calculate the hash and make it an ID. Which has benefits like:

1. De-duplication. If you have the same blob (same file in Git) - you won't duplicate the data - it's going to be stored once and be referenced from different places. Which means that:

   - You can copy same file or folder and there won't be any duplicates in Git "database", just multiple references to the same blob. So the amount of space to be stored/transferred is minimized.
   - When you rename/move files - their content won't be added to Git again with a different name. Git will generate the same hash and thus will quickly recognize that no new objects need to be created. Again - same objects will be referenced from different locations.
   - If you remove the file one one commit and then add it again in another commit - still no new objects are created since old ones still reside in `.git` (they're referenced by older commits thus have to stay in `.git`).
2. Also how can you quickly show diff between 2 commits? For Git it's easy since folders are just objects (trees) that reference blobs and other folders - and this information is also content-addressable. So if a tree (folder) now references a different blob/tree (or their names changed) - the hash-based ID will change. So Git can first check the hashes of trees (folders) to see if their content is different and whether Git has to step inside to check for other differences.
3. You don't have to store additional database (meta-information) about which *surrogate* ID references which data. The ID can be deduced from the content.

PS: though points 1-2 can be achieved with a surrogate ID too, you'd simply have to store hash *along* with those IDs. So before storing a new file you'd have to calculate its hash and look up a surrogate ID by the hash in the database. Less convenient, but possible.

Comment: yeah this one is clear. so. #3 and #4 are all good reasons for hashes and #1 and #2 seem like a side effect of those.I mean, 1 and 2 were not the primary reason for using hash-addresses

Comment: I don't really see #2 as relevant here.  Renames/moves are easy on all common *nix filesystems, and they are not content-addressable.  The key to this is that the identity of the file (or `BLOB`) for storage purposes is a separate thing from the human-readable path/filename

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, if you ask Git to rename/move files then yes, it's not a problem. But if you did that externally (with `mv`) - Git didn't participate and has no information about what happened. So hash-based ID helps finding out that this object already existed and we don't have to add it again.

Comment: There are a couple misconceptions in what you just said.  It makes no difference whetehr you tell git to move a file or move it externally; either way, git records "file removed at path X; file created at path Y".  More to the point, you're conflating the application of deduping on the "file created at path Y" side of that, with the ease of the rename itself.  As I noted already, systems that are not content-addressable have exactly the same ease renaming files.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, systems that are not content-addressable (typical File Systems) are _told_ to move/rename files. They are the ones _doing the action_. Git on the other hand has "state before" and "state after". So during `git add` it has to realize that "state after" is actually the same as before since the ID already exists, hence new blob isn't created. _you're conflating the application of deduping ... with the ease of the rename itself_ - Yep. I'm merely giving examples on when de-duping takes place. So point #2 is more of a sub-point to #1. Maybe I should re-structure this part..

Comment: You're talking as though moving files in git were the only thing in the world, and as a result you're missing the point.  If I have a filesystem, and I want to move a file that it's storing, then the ease of doing so has ZERO to do with whether that file system is content addressable, period.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I totally agree with that. But I don't think you understand what I'm trying to convey.. I rephrased it, now it all is a part of #1.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, concurrency.

If you treat the hashes as logically being the content of the file, then each git object is an immutable copy-on-write object.

Two chunks of code can interact with an immutable copy-on-write object concurrently and never, every collide with each other.  The only interaction they have is going to be manipulating reference counts.

If instead git objects logically had references to other objects, the concurrency problem explodes.  Avoiding the insanity of lock-based concurrency becomes near impossible, which is one of the reasons why non-git SCS are so bad.

When you try to synchronize your git-repo state, you start off by pushing your immutable objects up.  If someone else is doing the same, the remote repo can tell you not to bother: but if you ignore the remote repo, it is harmless, because creating the same immutable object twice is a safe operation.

The only point of contention comes when you attempt to modify the parts of git that *aren't* logically immutable -- branches.

Here, git relies on atomic read-modify-write operations.  You state "main, which used to refer to immutable state X1, now refers to state X2".  If someone else concurrently says they want to move main from state X1 to X3, either operation could run and the other one fails.

On large projects it is exactly this step where solutions external to git are used, as this is the one part of the git workflow that doesn't admit the beauty of immutable concurrency.

But the immutable hash based system removes almost all concurrency issues, and git was designed as a highly concurrent source control system.  It is so concurrent that people can clone a git repo, walk away for a year, and come back and still be able to talk to the original repo about how their changes relate to everyone elses.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone changes some file in the git repo, it will break all the
> commits which point to it. Thus you will for sure know that something
> bad has happend. But is it really that useful?

This is the motivation behind using a *strong* (kind of; not in terms of
security) hash hunction over something like a simple checksum.

Back in the BitKeeper days (the VCS they used before Git) The Linux
project experienced a break-in to the source code.[1] Some malicious actor
tried to change the code without anyone noticing. Thankfully though
BitKeeper had some checksum mechanism that happened to catch this.

Think of the Git repository that Linus Torvalds uses: he is the only one
who can commit to it. So what happens when he gets a pull request (via
email)? If he pulls it he can see the differences that it introduces and
be confident that the history prior to the merge is sound. Why? Because if
someone modified the history then the operation would fail since the SHA1
values of the incoming commits wouldn't match up.

Okay, but SHA1 isn't secure. So what if someone spent some money on
computing the same SHA1 as some commit that he has in his own history?
Well then the “forged” object would still not make its way into his
repository because *his own* (not forged) objects would take precedence
over any *incoming* blobs.

With all those caveats though: these were claims made in 2007. Maybe
technology has changed to the point that Git does not have the same
guarantees that it once had (or thought it had). But the fact remains that
the point (the intent) of this chaining of hash values (where changing
just a small thing a thousand commits ago invalidates all ancestors)
was/is to prevent people from changing the history of your repository
without you noticing.

#### Notes

1. This is based on my recollection of the 2007 Linus Torvalds Google Talk